# Keeping first and last rows of a pgfplotstable with longtable on a page

Tags: line-breaking, longtable, pgfplotstable

I am using `pgfplotstable` along with `longtable`. Everything works good, but sometimes a single row can be on one page, which is kind of ugly. How can i keep the first 3 and last 3 rows of the table on one page?

Thanks!

---

Here is the code I have been using so far:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
    end table=\end{longtable},
    every head row/.style={output empty row},
    every first row/.append style={before row={%
            \caption{Runtime results in milliseconds of the algorithms \ref{alg:search-rg} and \ref{alg:search-rg-astar} tested on the potato network.}\label{tbl:results_potato}\\\hline%
        Depth & \textsc{Bfs} & \textsc{Norm} & \textsc{NowmW} & \textsc{Heur}\\\hline
            \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{\pgfplotstablecols}{c}{{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- continued}}\\\hline
            Depth & \textsc{Bfs} & \textsc{Norm} & \textsc{NowmW} & \textsc{Heur}\\\hline
            \endhead
            \hline
            \multicolumn{\pgfplotstablecols}{r}{Continued on the next page.}
            \endfoot
            \hline
            \endlastfoot
        },
    },
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    columns/Depth/.style={column name=Depth, column type={l}},
    columns/Bfs/.style={column name=\textsc{Bfs}, column type={n{5}{3}}},
    columns/Norm/.style={column name=\textsc{Norm}, column type={n{5}{3}}},
    columns/NormW/.style={column name=\textsc{NormW}, column type={n{5}{3}}},
    columns/Heur/.style={column name=\textsc{Heur}, column type={n{5}{3}}},
]{potato.csv}
```

Basically, told pgfplotstable to use a longtable, remove its own heading creation to customize them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Could you edit your question to include a minimal example document that reproduces the behaviour, so we have something to get started with when working on a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Please always post complete documents not just fragments.

You can use the keys to add commands to control page breaking. Here I force a page break at line 6 to stop just one line + the heading being on page 2.

---

```
1,2,3,4,5
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
11,22,33,44,55
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,longtable}

\setlength\textheight{15\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    begin table=\begin{longtable},
    end table=\end{longtable},
    every head row/.style={output empty row},
    every first row/.append style={before row={%
            \caption{Runtime results in milliseconds of the algorithms zzz and zzzz tested on the potato network.}\label{tbl:results_potato}\\\hline%
        Depth & \textsc{Bfs} & \textsc{Norm} & \textsc{NowmW} & \textsc{Heur}\\\hline
            \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{\pgfplotstablecols}{c}{{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- continued}}\\\hline
            Depth & \textsc{Bfs} & \textsc{Norm} & \textsc{NowmW} & \textsc{Heur}\\\hline
            \endhead
            \hline
            \multicolumn{\pgfplotstablecols}{r}{Continued on the next page.}
            \endfoot
            \hline
            \endlastfoot
        },
    },
    every nth row={6}{before row=\pagebreak},%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    columns/Depth/.style={column name=Depth, column type={l}},
    columns/Bfs/.style={column name=\textsc{Bfs}, column type={n{5}{3}}},
    columns/Norm/.style={column name=\textsc{Norm}, column type={n{5}{3}}},
    columns/NormW/.style={column name=\textsc{NormW}, column type={n{5}{3}}},
    columns/Heur/.style={column name=\textsc{Heur}, column type={n{5}{3}}},
]{potato.csv}

\end{document}
```